# remove all alarms of all overdue reminders with AppleScript on OS X

Tags: applescript, reminders

I want to remove all alarms / notifications (there may be none, one or more than one) of all overdue reminders in the Reminders app of OS X.

I tried to use AppleScript for this, but having troubles understanding how to properly work with *objects*. I figured out how to get all those reminders, though:

```
tell application "Reminders"
    activate
    set myRemList to every reminder whose due date is less than (current date) as list
    repeat with myitem in myRemList
        log (get properties of myitem)
    end repeat
end tell
```

Is this code usable (any fatal mistakes I'm not aware of)? How can I remove the alarms?

[Edit]

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

Consider this one which reminds me to call Jon Doe:

[image]

The item is due today and a reminder is set to notify me at 14.00 (2 pm). When my planning has changed there are few of those items, popping up their reminders ("call jon doe" in this example). I want that "remind me" property to be unticked for all overdue items.

Comment: Have you tried just running that code? There's nothing in there that will cause the system to explode; all it's doing is logging properties.

Comment: @tubedogg yes, but it's only the beginning as it does not what I want to achieve: removing the alarms of the reminders

Comment: I have now updated my answer, hopefully addressing the need/want expressed in your edited OP. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Did my updated answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was no fatal mistake in the *code* shown in the OP, however the proper way to use `current date`, in this case, is by letting the current application do it, not Reminders, as it actually errors out but does recover, hence not fatal. Nonetheless one should write *code* that's not going to needlessly error out. So, before the `tell application "Reminders"` *code block*, set `current date` to a *variable* and use the *variable* within the *Reminders code block*, as shown in the *code* further below.

Note that I personally do not use the Reminders app, however going by what's exposed in Reminders's AppleScript Dictionary, the following *properties*, not marked as`r/o`, are what can be programmatically changed for the `reminder` *class*.

> **name** (text) : the name of the reminder 
>   **id** (text, r/o) : the unique identifier of the reminder 
>   **body** (text) : the notes attached to the reminder 
>   **completed** (boolean) : Is the reminder completed? 
>   **completion date** (date) : the completion date of the reminder 
>   **container** (list, r/o) : the container of the reminder 
>   **creation date** (date, r/o) : the creation date of the reminder 
>   **due date** (date) : the due date of the reminder 
>   **modification date** (date, r/o) : the modification date of the reminder 
>   **remind me date** (date) : the remind date of the reminder 
>   **priority** (integer) : the priority of the reminder

As a test, I created a reminder named "Test" and set the **remind me [√]** *check box* to *yesterdays date*, so as to conform with the *search parameter* in the *code* further below.

Then, in Script Editor, I used the following line of *code* to get its *properties*.

```
tell application "Reminders" to get properties of reminder named "Test"
```

It returned:

- `{due date:date "Saturday, September 10, 2016 2:00:00 PM", modification date:date "Sunday, September 11, 2016 1:49:35 PM", class:reminder, body:missing value, completed:false, completion date:missing value, id:"3F0EF538-5DF6-4F1C-8024-922B5D45EB9B", name:"Test", container:list id "9EB58C9B-EF63-4B72-88C3-A4FFA3C7272F" of application "Reminders", priority:0, creation date:date "Sunday, September 11, 2016 1:49:13 PM", remind me date:date "Saturday, September 10, 2016 2:00:00 PM"}`

I then manually unchecked the **remind me []** *check box* and ran the `... get properties ...` *code* again.

It returned:

- `{due date:missing value, modification date:date "Sunday, September 11, 2016 1:49:35 PM", class:reminder, body:missing value, completed:false, completion date:missing value, id:"3F0EF538-5DF6-4F1C-8024-922B5D45EB9B", name:"Test", container:list id "9EB58C9B-EF63-4B72-88C3-A4FFA3C7272F" of application "Reminders", priority:0, creation date:date "Sunday, September 11, 2016 1:49:13 PM", remind me date:missing value}`

The primary difference between the two was the first and last *items* in the *list*, i.e., the `due date` and the `remind me date`, went from `due date:date "Saturday, September 10, 2016 2:00:00 PM"` to `due date:missing value` with the same for `remind me date`, having `remind me date:missing value` too.

So I tested the *code* below using both *preferences*, `due date` and `remind me date` just to see if there was any difference and there wasn't, as removing one removed the other.

The following *code* **will remove both the `due date` and `remind me date`** from any Reminder that's older then `current date` and has not been marked `completed`, at the time the *code* is run, as this is what occurs, at least to the *properties* of a `reminder`, in one has manually unchecked the **remind me []** *check box*.

```
set curDate to current date

tell application "Reminders"
    activate
    set myRemList to every reminder whose due date is less than curDate as list
    repeat with myitem in myRemList
        if completed of myitem is false then
            delete remind me date of myitem
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

---

The *code* above can also be written as shown below. This actually is a better way to write it, as it makes for a smaller *list* returned because it's then only creating a list of *items* (`reminders`) that have not yet been marked as  *completed*. As after all, ones already marked as *completed* are not going to trigger an "alarm".

```
set curDate to current date

tell application "Reminders"
    activate
    set myRemList to every reminder whose completed is false and due date is less than curDate as list
    repeat with myitem in myRemList
        delete remind me date of myitem
    end repeat
end tell
```

---

Based upon your edited OP, if this does not do what is needed, then I do not know what else I can offer, as I can only work within what *properties* are exposed and editable.

Note: I was not able to reproduce the reminder as shown in your edit, i.e. the line starting with "due" directly under the **[] At a Location** *check box* and above "repeat **None**". However, what is now offered as the answer to "remove all alarms of all overdue reminders with AppleScript on OS X" does mimic the manual action of unchecking the **remind me []** *check box*, which is what you've now asked for through the edit made to the OP. I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: great, good to know, thank you! do you know additionally know how to just remove the alarms of the reminders (instead of deleting them)?

Comment: @muffel, Here's the issue... Personally I do not use the Reminders app and I can only go by what's exposed in the AppleScript Dictionary of the target App. The Reminders's AppleScript Dictionary doesn't expose a property named "alarm", or similar, for the properties of the `reminder` _class_. So I'm not sure to what you're referring, sorry.

Comment: thanks again! I edited my question in order to show what I exactly want to achieve, please have a look.